# Why is glOrtho not changing anything?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut, opengl-compat

This function does not change anything even though I already called glOrtho(). What's wrong with the code? Did I miss something?

```
void glKeyCallback(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
  if (key == 'z'){
    width -= 10; height -= 10;
    cout << "Z" << endl;
    cout << width << " " << height << endl;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  }else if (key == 'x'){
    width += 10; height += 10;
    cout << "X" << endl;
    cout << width << " " << height << endl;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  }
}
```

I expected for the scene to zoom in / out when I pressed z or x. But it does not change anything. For the record, I have already registered this on `glutKeyboardFunc`

Comment: Calling GL functions in callbacks is iffy, because the callback may be running in the wrong thread. Better call them only where you do your actual rendering.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  For all we know you aren't redrawing on a regular basis; your `glutKeyboardFunc()` certainly isn't calling `glutPostRedisplay()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is not a scene graph, it's a drawing API. Just changing the projection matrix will do nothing. You also have to redraw things.